# Why is my extension trait not being recognized for Cursor?

Tags: rust

A minimum working example of the problem. Reading [this article](http://xion.io/post/code/rust-extension-traits.html) on extension traits, I tried to implement my own.

```
use std::io::{Read, Cursor};
use std::io;

pub trait KRead {
    fn read1(&mut self) -> io::Result<i32>;
}

impl KRead for Read {
    fn read1(&mut self) -> io::Result<i32> {
        let mut buf = [0u8];
        self.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
        Ok(buf[0] as i32)
    }
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let input_data = [47u8, 56u8];
    let mut input_buffer = Cursor::new(input_data);
    assert_eq!(47, input_buffer.read1()?);
    assert_eq!(56, input_buffer.read1()?);
    Ok(())
}
```

but compilation fails with

```
No method named `read1` found for struct `std::io::Cursor<[u8; 2]>` in the current scope
No method named `read1` found for struct `std::io::Cursor<[u8; 2]>` in the current scope
```

but `Cursor` implements `Read` so I thought it would automatically pick up my extension trait. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
impl KRead for Read {
  ...
}
```

If you compile this on recent versions of Rust, you should get a warning.

```
warning: trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated
```

That's because what you've written is actually

```
impl KRead for dyn Read {
  ...
}
```

That is, you have *not* said "every `Read` is a `KRead`". You've said "specifically the trait *object* type `dyn Read` is a `KRead`", which is much narrower and less useful. If you want the former, you need to use a generic type argument.

```
impl<T> KRead for T where T: Read {
    fn read1(&mut self) -> io::Result<i32> {
        let mut buf = [0u8];
        self.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
        Ok(buf[0] as i32)
    }
}
```